# Moving JavaScripts from WordPress Template Header to Footer

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I need some help moving the JavaScript from the header to the footer.

```
<script src="<?php print get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/js/jquery.uniform.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php print get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/js/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php print get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/js/jquery.xml2json.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php print get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/css/uniform.default.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php print get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
```

I only want this JavaScripts to be on the bottom of one page, not my entire WordPress theme, this is for a form.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

```
1 - copy your script code from header and remove it from there.
2 - Goto your theme->footer.php and edit this page, Goto end of page after wp_footer(); function paste your script.
3 - Save and run.

<?php if(is_page(your_page_id)) {
   <script src="<?php print get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/js/jquery.uniform.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="<?php print get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/js/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="<?php print get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/js/jquery.xml2json.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php print get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/css/uniform.default.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php print get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
}?>
```

Comment: I only want these JavaScripts to be on the bottom of one page, which is this custom template "form" that will only be used on one of the pages.

Comment: So I don't need to edit the functions.php or the footer.php files?

Comment: you need to put this in the footer.php file

Comment: My page is blank now, is this ok:

Comment: yes, this will work only for that page which you will add id.

Answer (score 0):

You should be properly enqueuing your styles and scripts with the WordPress function [wp_enqueue_script();](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

The fifth parameter lets your choose to load the style/script in the footer.

i.e
`wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );`

Update: This is not tested but should work.

```
function enqueue_my_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'uniform', get_template_directory_uri() . 'library/js/jquery.uniform.min.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-ui', get_template_directory_uri() . '/library/js/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'xml2json', get_template_directory_uri() . '/library/js/jquery.xml2json.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );

wp_enqueue_style( 'uniform-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/library/css/uniform.default.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'ui-lightness', get_template_directory_uri() . '/library/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.css' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_scripts' );
```

You will need to read up on the function and add any dependencies such as jQuery.

Comment: So I wouldn't have to edit the footer.php or functions.php files?

Comment: I have updated the answer and you will need to add the code into your functions.php file.